# Nine patch Image Shrinks in splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, nine-patch

[image]

I have created the following  nine patch image as splash screen i want the center icon to not  to resize.But when use it it get shrink in media pad 7 lite .what am i doing wrong.I have saved it as screen.9.png in  drawable*.
In config.xml  i have used this line

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
```

Comment: post the code where you used it.,

Comment: Nine-patch dynamically stretches and shrinks an image at runtime.

Comment: but when i run in  media pad 7 lite it shrinks still.Is my patches that i have used is correct?

Comment: using the cordava cli the nine patch image doesnot work I created my app in eclipse now its working thanks everybody